# extract_table function causes R to Crash

Tags: r, rjava, tabulizer

I am simply using:

`extract_tables('/Users/ben/OneDrive/Utah Local Governments Trust/Underwriting - Documents/Data Analysis/Emod Calculation/Expected Loss Rates, D-Ratio, Etc.pdf')`

after loading:

`library(tabulizer)`

`library(tabulizerjars)`

It says it needs to use Java SE 6 to open Rstudio but I can open it just fine with the latest java before running the funciton.